# Apache serves an old SSL certificate

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, raspberry-pi, certificate

I'm hosting a webpage with Apache on a Raspberry Pi (Debian), and can't seem to get the server to issue the current certificate.  I generated a self-signed SSL certificate in `/home/pi/ssl/` with:

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -x509 -nodes -days 365 -out example.com.pem -keyout example.com.key
```

Apache looks up the `.pem` and `.key` file pair from file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/owncloud.conf`, which contains:

```
SSLCertificateFile    /home/pi/ssl/example.com.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/pi/ssl/example.com.key
```

When I delete these files and restart Apache I get error `[FAIL] Reloading web server config: apache2 failed!`.  This error doesn't happen when restarting after a new certificate file pair has been generated, so Apache does seem to be calling the certificate.

However the certificate that comes through in browsers (Chrome Incognito or FF/Safari private windows, and even a browser on a computer that surely never requested the domain before) is an old certificate I generated a month ago - see below:

[image: old certificate details]

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Just to be very very sure: can you run `openssl x509 -in /home/pi/ssl/example.com.pem -text -noout` to see which common name it shows?

Comment: And just to be sure: there is no other certificate configured anywhere in your apache config, i.e. no other certificate on any virtual host?

Comment: @Arjan `example.com` - see [gist](https://gist.github.com/geotheory/28fd6fb15c03539d492f)

Comment: Solved! `grep -i -r "SSLCertificateChainFile" /etc/apache2/` showed `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl` still had references to the default 'snakeoil' certificate.  Commenting these out and the browser returns the customised certificate.

Comment: Nice, but weird: `sites-available` should not be used, unless linked into `sites-enabled`... Still then: please post it as answer. :-)

Comment: @geotheory If you have found a solution you should be able to post is as an answer below and in a day or two you should be able to mark it as correct.

Comment: Related: become your own CA and avoid all the browser warnings: [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21297139/608639) And how to create a well formed server certificate accepted by all browsers: [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27931596/608639)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the certificate being issued was for some reason the default Apache "snakeoil" certificate.  I established this by:

```
grep -i -r "SSLCertificateChainFile" /etc/apache2/
```

.. which returned 2 lines from file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl` that referenced the snakeoil certificate.  I commented these lines out and the browser now returns the customised certificate.

Comment: *"the default Apache "snakeoil" certificate..."* - haha, yes. Delete that certificate and its private key... Its one of those things that once you know about it, you actively hunt it.

Answer (score 1):

A common source of such problems is multiple running instances of Apache. The config changes are picked up by a process that you (re)start but the request is served by an old process which is running with old configuration.

Stop the service:

```
service apache2 stop
```

Check if the site is still accessible. If yes, then you have identified the cause.

Now run

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

It will give you list of running apache2 process and their PIDs. Kill them all (Note, this command may also return unrelated processes with Apache in their name/user etc. like Apache Tomcat, you might not want kill them.)

```
kill <pid>
```

Run ps aux again and ensure that processes are no longer running.

Check again if site is accessible. It shouldn't be.

Now start apache service

```
service apache2 start
```

Verify that the new certificate is being served.

If you don't want to kill processes, you may reboot the system. It will have the same effect.